# Creating rails database model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have table A with some fields i.e :

```
id
name
release_date
```

And I have table B which contains two table A entities i.e

```
id
from
to
```

(from and to are ids from table A)

How do I connect these two entities in model so I can use dot operator to access Bs from A?

**About Design**

From table A record another record A is created so I want to keep track of which was created from which record.

So this is why table B exists, so I know from which A was made from which A

Comment: Can you elaborate some more on this design? That's the relationship between A and B?

Comment: @Michael Szyndel I hope that answers ur question

Comment: So you basically have a tree of records? Why not have an additional column in A like `parent_id`?

Comment: And for managing tree structure I tink most popular solution is  Ancestry gem https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) relationship. There's more information about it in [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) where you can check the migrations needed too.

Comment: HABTM is generally discouraged in favour of `has_many :through` and it is even more discouraged to give that answer to such a broad question.

Answer (score 1):

Try

in class B

```
has_many :froms, :foreign_key => "from" , :class_name=>"A"
has_many :tos, :foreign_key => "to" , :class_name=>"A"
```

Comment: It could be `has_one` as well :)

Comment: This doesn't allow you to access Bs from A, you need a belongs_to in class A, but you would need a separate field based on whether it was a 'from' A or a 'to' A

Comment: When I try to access A.froms I get #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy:0x582f406>

Comment: A collection proxy is just a fancy array that contains instances of ActiveRecord models. try Yevgeniy's suggestion, change the has_many to has_one (maybe change to 'from' and 'to' instead of the plural to keep things sane)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use many to many relationship using `through` follow this link it will clear your all doubts regarding relationships

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association